# Как разбить строку на блоки Regex'ами?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Надо разбить строку на поля. Поля выделены кавычками (двойными или одинарными):

```
"поле 1" 'поле 2''поле 3' ...
```

При этом в поле можно записать кавычки через экранирование:

```
"'это' одно \"поле\""
```

Такие поля можно расспарсить следующей регуляркой:

```
"\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"" для полей в двойных кавычках
"\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\'" для полей в одинарных кавычках
```

Например:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, "\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\""))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Как можно сделать тоже самое, но получить последовательно не только `Math'и`, но и текст между полями?

Comment: Regex.Split() не совсем подходит, т.к. будут возвращены только блоки между полями

Comment: Думаю, вам нужны не регулярки, а нормальный парсер HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если поместить все регулярное выражение в скобки, получится так называемая [группа с захватом](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). Передав такое выражение в метод Regex.Split, вы получите необходимый результат.

```
(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")
```

Из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any
>   captured text is included in the resulting string array. For example,
>   if you split the string "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within
>   capturing parentheses, the returned array includes a string element
>   that contains the hyphen.

Если в выражении переданном методу Regex.Split используются отмеченные подвыражения, то захваченный ими текст добавляется в результирующий массив. Например, при разбиении строки "грушево-сливовое" используя знак тире заключенный в скобки, результирующий массив так же включает элемент содержащий одно тире.

```
["грушево", "-", "сливовое"]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не подскажете еще, можно ли уместить эти две регулярки в одну? Присутствует проверка, что внутри кавычек нет других кавычек этого же типа без экранирования: `[^\"\\\\]` , из-за чего просто заменить `\"` на `[\"']` по идее не подходит'

Comment: А вы их с помощью оператора `|` объедините: `(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")|(\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\')`